# CosmosDB emulator not working with Flask and MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to learn how to use CosmosDB with Flask. I went through the tutorial on building a flask app using CosmosDB for MongoDB API(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-mongodb-flask#run-the-web-app). I keep getting the error:

```
pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

The emulator is running, but it will not connect. I followed the instructions and got it to work once before, but now it no longer works.

EDIT: I do have the Python Extension for VSCode

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the  Python extension? You can go through this [Build a Flask app using Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/cosmosdb-flask-mongo-sample/cosmosdb-flask-mongo-sample/) and verify if you have done it correcly.